# why can i access jQuery's clone(true,true) even after i exit the function it was called in?

Tags: jquery, clone

i used jQuery's clone(true,true) method to clone my element and store it in a variable newElem within a function. However, this was done when a button is clicked (inside a function).

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){var newElem=$('#student1').clone(true,true) })
```

I realized that the newElem variable (in which the clone is stored) is accessible even after i exit the function. Although my code is working as i want, i am confused as to why a variable declared within a function can be called even after i exit it.

can someone explain if it just a feature of clone() to make it work as such/am i wrong?

Thanks

Comment: That should not be true with that code above....Is that the real code?

Comment: hi, it's just a part of my code. my entire code was long, so did not include it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code looks like this:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    var newElem=$('#student1').clone(true,true);
});

// newElem is not available here
```

Then, the `newElem` variable here is a local variable and is ONLY available within that particular invocation of that function.  It is declared in the scope of your callback function and is only available within that function unless you pass its value to some other function when you call some other function.

> I realized that the `newElem` variable (in which the clone is stored) is
>   accessible even after i exit the function.

You are likely mistaken about that.  The `newElem` variable is NOT available outside the callback function.  Since what you have shown is likely a condensed down version of your real code (since what you have shown doesn't actually do anything productive), there is probably something else in your real code that is influencing the behavior here and you would have to show us more context to help you understand that.  If, for example, you created some closures inside this callback function that have a reference to `newElem`, then it will stay alive inside your callback function until those closures are no longer active.  But, we'd need to see the rest of your real code to comment further on that.

> can someone explain if it just a feature of clone() to make it work as
>   such/am i wrong?

This has nothing to do with `.clone()`.  The way it behaves is how the Javascript language is designed.

Comment: oh okay..i just rechecked my code and found the "bug"..thanks- @jfriend00